# What is the best way to authenticate an user in two different domains?

Tags: asp.net, .net, security, authentication, web

I currently have 2 websites.  One is  "www.myApp.com"  and the second one is "www.anotherApp.com".

If a user logs in in the first site, i want to let him enter the second site without signing in again.  (the user logs in only one time)

How can this be achieved in a secure manner?

I am using .Net MVC 3 over IIS 6 and i'm using WebForms authentication in both sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure [Forms Authentication Across Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that by using simple [FormAuthenciation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

With FormAuthenciation, you can only share authentication between - **apple.myApp.com** and **orange.myApp.com**

The main reason is **www.myApp.com** cannot read cookie set by **www.anotherApp.com**, and vice versa.

If you want to achieve SSO on differnt urls, you might want to look at [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517291.aspx).